# restrict object owner in postgresql to not able to grant permissions to other users

Tags: database, postgresql

Essentially -- In postgres , how to give a db user ability to create object in a schema  but not able to grant permissions on that object to others users.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a "default permission" (IE, permissions on NEW objects). The "Grant option" needs to be revoked.

Keep in mind that this only affects NEW tables/objects. You'll have to go back and manually alter the permissions on older objects manually or create a script to do it.

```
 alter default permissions
 for USER_HERE
 revoke grant option for all
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-priv.html)

> The special privileges of the object owner (i.e., the right to do DROP, GRANT, REVOKE, etc.) are always implicit in being the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked.

Since these special privileges cannot be revoked, I think the only way to prevent the object owner from granting or revoking privileges is to take ownership away (make some other user the owner) after the object is created.

But this seems a strange thing to do, and I think you'll probably get better answers by asking about the real problem rather than asking about one solution. That is, "How do I prevent an object's owner from granting privileges?" is not the real problem--it's one "solution" to an unstated problem. Think about what the *real* problem is.